# Ordering of number and word in PlotLegends

Tags: plotting

I have:

```
datapp = {1, 2, 9}

ListLinePlot[datapp, PlotLegends -> Placed[Superscript[10, 2] "Bacteria", Right]]
```

[image]

Regardless of the ordering in the command of PlotLegends, always "Bacteria" appears first. How can I have the number $10^2$ before "Bacteria?"

Comment: try `Placed[Row[{Superscript[10, 2], " Bacteria"}], Right]`?

Comment: ... or `Placed[Row[{Superscript[10, 2], "Bacteria"}, Spacer[3]], Right]]`?

Comment: Or `StringForm["`` Bacteria", HoldForm[10^2]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[datapp, 
 PlotLegends ->  Placed[Row[{Superscript[10, 2], "Bacteria"}, Spacer[3]], Right]]
```

[image]

Comment: it is the separator as in `Row[{"foo", "bar", "buzz"}, XXX]`